# Problem when texturing triangles using glVertexPointer()

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I'm having a problem for displaying a single quad, here is how i do :

[image]

```
//note: this code is only for 2 triangles, while on picture there is 4 triangles
float tex_coord[] =
{
   0.0, 0.0, //3
   0.0, 1.0, //2
   1.0, 1.0, //0
   1.0, 1.0, //0
   1.0, 0.0, //1
   0.0, 0.0  //3
}; 

int indexes[] = 
{
    3, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3
}

 glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
 glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
   glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
   glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tex_coord);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
 glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
 glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: Your first image has 4 triangles but the second one has only 2

Comment: Yes you are right but problem is the same with 2 or 4. I updated picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you need 4 texture coords; one for each position in vertices.

tex_coord[2] & text_coord[3] are the same, even though they are for different vertices.

Change text_coord[2] to 1.0,0 ; should fix the problem.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked! My mistake was to think i have to provide a pair of texture coords every time a vertex is used in a triangle, while I should only give one texture coord per vertex (no mater how much times the vertex is used )